Why is the row coloring broken?
I'm not quite sory why the row coloring isn't working here. For other tables with the same "schema" it's working fine... Does someone have an idea about what's wrong?
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

% Document
\begin{document}
    % Works fine
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Prototyp Art} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Presentation Prototyp} & Ein schnell erstelltes Modell, dessen primaere Aufgabe darin besteht, dem Kunden die Realisierbarkeit des Projekts sowie die Uebereinstimmung mit den Anforderungen zu demonstrieren.
            Wichtig fuer den Vertragsschluss mit potenziellen Kunden. \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Proper Prototyp} & Ein funktionierendes Softwaresystem, das spezifische UI-Aspekte oder Teile der Funktionalitaet veranschaulicht und der Klaerung von Problemen dient. \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Breadboard} & Ein technischer Prototyp, der der Klaerung konstruktionsbedingter Fragen dient, die aus den Systemspezifikationen abgeleitet werden, und ohne Nutzerbewertung auskommt. \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Pilot System} & Ein umfassendes Softwaresystem, das keine Unterscheidung zwischen Prototyp und Anwendungssystem zulaesst und ein hohes Detailniveau erfordert. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    % Works not so fine lmao
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            & \textbf{Mo} & \textbf{S} & \textbf{Co} & \textbf{W} \\
            \midrule
            Anforderung 1 & \textbf{x}  &            &             &            \\
            Anforderung 2 &             & \textbf{x} &             &            \\
            Anforderung 3 & \textbf{x}  &            &             &            \\
            Anforderung 4 &             &            & \textbf{x}  &            \\
            Anforderung 5 & \textbf{x}  &            &             &            \\
            Anforderung 6 &             &            &             & \textbf{x} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}




Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a full minimal working example which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document} instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

As you wish ^^ Thx for helping

You need “something” in the blank cells.
I suggest to define local commands in order to get a better input for the second table.
I also suggest a few enhancements (p for the first column in the top table, how to avoid gaps, how to change the widths in the bottom table).
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
}
\toprule
\textbf{Prototyp Art} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Presentation Prototyp}
& Ein schnell erstelltes Modell, dessen primaere Aufgabe darin besteht, 
  dem Kunden die Realisierbarkeit des Projekts sowie die Uebereinstimmung 
  mit den Anforderungen zu demonstrieren.
  Wichtig fuer den Vertragsschluss mit potenziellen Kunden.
\\
\midrule
\textbf{Proper Prototyp}
& Ein funktionierendes Softwaresystem, das spezifische UI-Aspekte oder 
  Teile der Funktionalitaet veranschaulicht und der Klaerung von
  Problemen dient.
\\
\midrule
\textbf{Breadboard} 
& Ein technischer Prototyp, der der Klaerung konstruktionsbedingter 
  Fragen dient, die aus den Systemspezifikationen abgeleitet werden, 
  und ohne Nutzerbewertung auskommt.
\\
\midrule
\textbf{Pilot System} 
& Ein umfassendes Softwaresystem, das keine Unterscheidung zwischen 
  Prototyp und Anwendungssystem zulaesst und ein hohes Detailniveau 
  erfordert.
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\newcommand{\Y}{\textbf{x}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mbox{}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=1.4\hsize}X
  >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.9\hsize}X
  >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.9\hsize}X
  >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.9\hsize}X
  >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.9\hsize}X
}
\toprule
\mbox{} & \textbf{Mo} & \textbf{S} & \textbf{Co} & \textbf{W} \\
\midrule
Anforderung 1 & \Y & \N & \N & \N \\
Anforderung 2 & \N & \Y & \N & \N \\
Anforderung 3 & \Y & \Y & \N & \N \\
Anforderung 4 & \N & \N & \Y & \N \\
Anforderung 5 & \Y & \N & \Y & \N \\
Anforderung 6 & \N & \Y & \N & \Y \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Just to please my eye, a comparison: no background colors, no boldface, no unnecessary stretching to the text width.
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Packages
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  c
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
  @{}
}
\toprule
Prototyp Art & Beschreibung \\
\midrule
\splitcell{Presentation \\ Prototyp}
& Ein schnell erstelltes Modell, dessen primaere Aufgabe darin besteht, 
  dem Kunden die Realisierbarkeit des Projekts sowie die Uebereinstimmung 
  mit den Anforderungen zu demonstrieren.
  Wichtig fuer den Vertragsschluss mit potenziellen Kunden.
\\
\midrule
\splitcell{Proper \\ Prototyp}
& Ein funktionierendes Softwaresystem, das spezifische UI-Aspekte oder 
  Teile der Funktionalitaet veranschaulicht und der Klaerung von
  Problemen dient.
\\
\midrule
Breadboard
& Ein technischer Prototyp, der der Klaerung konstruktionsbedingter 
  Fragen dient, die aus den Systemspezifikationen abgeleitet werden, 
  und ohne Nutzerbewertung auskommt.
\\
\midrule
Pilot System
& Ein umfassendes Softwaresystem, das keine Unterscheidung zwischen 
  Prototyp und Anwendungssystem zulaesst und ein hohes Detailniveau 
  erfordert.
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

% Works not so fine lmao
\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\newcommand{\Y}{$\times$}
\newcommand{\N}{\mbox{}}

\begin{tabular*}{0.6\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c c c c @{}
}
\toprule
& Mo & S & Co & W \\
\midrule
Anforderung 1 & \Y & \N & \N & \N \\
Anforderung 2 & \N & \Y & \N & \N \\
Anforderung 3 & \Y & \Y & \N & \N \\
Anforderung 4 & \N & \N & \Y & \N \\
Anforderung 5 & \Y & \N & \Y & \N \\
Anforderung 6 & \N & \Y & \N & \Y \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you for the input... sadly its a "requirement" to stretch the tables for the Thesis. Maybe I'll remove the coloring. Thought it would make the table more readable

I don't know why this happen. If you insert to empty cells invisible characer, for example ~, then you will get desired result:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C C C C C}
            \toprule
 ~            & \textbf{Mo} & \textbf{S} & \textbf{Co} & \textbf{W} \\
            \midrule
Anforderung 1 & \textbf{x}  &            &             &            \\
Anforderung 2 & ~           & \textbf{x} & ~           & ~          \\
Anforderung 3 & \textbf{x}  &            &             &            \\
Anforderung 4 & ~           & ~          & \textbf{x}  & ~          \\
Anforderung 5 & \textbf{x}  &            & ~           &            \\
Anforderung 6 & ~           & ~          & ~           & \textbf{x} \\
\bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


Addendum:
More concide, less pron to errors is table with use of the tblr of tabularray package:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {X[1.2,c] *{4}{X[c, font=\bfseries]}},
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!25}
             }
    \toprule
                &   Mo  &   S   &   Co  &   W   \\
    \midrule
Anforderung 1   &   x   &       &       &       \\
Anforderung 2   &       &   x   &       &       \\
Anforderung 3   &   x   &       &       &       \\
Anforderung 4   &       &       &   x   &       \\
Anforderung 5   &   x   &       &       &       \\
Anforderung 6   &       &       &       &   x   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

In this MWE I make first column 20% wider as are other columns.


It worked!!! Thank you very much... I didn't know that I have to use "~" also while building tables. You saved my thesis :3

@LaTeXN00b, also me not. This seem to be bug. However, I add (just now) a new possible solution which has wuite shorter code and no problems as you were faced.

Wild guess: in chat David mentioned something about colortbl being possibly broken by some recent update (related to tagging?).

@campa, it may be. I only occasionaly read chat.

@Zarko that's a good hint. I will use 'tblr' instead
